# Убрать переносы строк при нажатии на ENTER

Tags: javascript

```
$('#chat_mess').keydown(function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.which;
  if(keyCode == 13) _chat._add()
});
```

При нажатии на Enter, добавляется пустая строка в конец. Как это убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно использовать событие *keypress*, а во-вторых - *event.preventDefault()* или *return false* в условии.

```
$('#chat_mess').keypress(function(event) {
    var keyCode = event.which;
    if(keyCode == 13) {
        _chat._add();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery вроде сам добавляет preventDefault если есть return false
keypress, если следовать стандартам, должен срабатывать только на символьные клавиши (но в разных браузерах по разному)

Answer (score 2):

добавить

```
return false;
```